# CSS div height fill remaing space and scroll if reach max height of screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have searched everywhere on the web for this but i couldn't find anyone that really fits me or even work. The answers that I found are very old and/or are not 100% what I am looking for so I hope if anyone can help me with this.

I use bootstrap 4 in my application so if it can be done with bootstrap then yeay but pure css is ok as well.

What I try to do is having 4 div side by side

example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <h1>Item 1</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
        <h1>Item 2</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <h1>Item 2</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <h1>Item 2</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

This works because of bootstrap 4 but now I also want the div height will extend till the bottom of the screen  and if the content of that div is longer then the screen height, then it should scroll (inside the div).

I was thinking about flex boxes but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use bootsrap 4 , `flex` is already involved.

If the idea is to let the row grow till 100% height of the viewport, then show a scroll bar within the child that will grow past that value, you need to create a custom class involving max-height and overflow:

custom class example

```
<div class="row h100-scroll  ">
```

selectors and rules to uses to start with

```
.h100-scroll .col {/* to scroll col individually*/
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

or

```
.h100-scroll  {/* to scroll the row itself */
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

---

demo below, run snippet and hover text on first col

```css
.h100-scroll .col {
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}

.col br {display:none;}
p:hover br {display:block;}
body {
  margin: 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap-grid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row h100-scroll  ">
  <div class="col">
    <h1>Item 1</h1>
    <p>hover me show the br and add a scrollbar<br/> .<br/> . <br/> .<br/> . <br/> .<br/> . <br/> .<br/> . <br/> .<br/> . <br/> .<br/> . <br/> .<br/> . <br/> .<br/> . <br/> .<br/> . <br/> .<br/> . <br/> .<br/> . <br/> .<br/> . <br/> .<br/> . <br/> .<br/> . <br/> .<br/> . <br/> .<br/> . <br/> .<br/> . <br/> .<br/> . <br/> .<br/> . <br/> .<br/> . <br/> .<br/> . <br/> .<br/> . 
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <h1>Item 2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <h1>Item 2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <h1>Item 2</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `max-height: 100vh;` that's the secret sauce right there.

Comment: this kinda works for me, I do have a header so vh is for me 80. The .col is also using some margin and some padding and the moment i minimise my browser (so less height) then the div will extends under the view of the screen. Is this because I use padding and margin on that .col? if so, what is a good solution?

Comment: Example, the first image you see black bar, thats my windows bar so that is good. 2e image i have opends up my console in my browser and than its get bad.
image good: https://gyazo.com/a6b8e96c8500b07d2ac86bdd092a387c
image bad: https://gyazo.com/dce3e3de3782d9592250c19922884ec6

Comment: @NielsLucas , if margins and header's height is known, then we can invol calc() to set the max-height. if your html structure is made of 1 container wrapping header and row, it can also be worked out . do you have an example of  your structure that shows your issue ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hg3u4e2d/1/

it isnt really working ín de snipped but I thats my structure, Do you know a better way of just sharing code like this? cause this is kinda wrong cause you think It should work when you press 'run' in the fiddle. But in this case it doesnt.

Comment: You can use https://codepen.io/pen (in parameters of css windows, you can easily add bootstrap4 library ) and also use https://www.webpagefx.com/web-design/html-ipsum/ to pickup fake contents  and http://dummyimage.com to generate fake images  Example to start from https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aVENQV

Comment: I worked it out. on the div that I want to make scrollable i use:
max-height: calc(100vh - 200px);

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do this in jQuery.
Explanation:

> If the height of the div is longer than height of the document, show a scroll in the div

Code:

```
$(document).ready(fuction(){

var docHeight = $(document).height();

var divHeight = $('.the-four-divs').height();
If(divHeight > docHeight){
$('.the-four-divs').css('overflow-x', 'scroll');

}

});
```

`

Hop it helps sir.

Comment: This doesn't seem to relate (`.the-four-divs` especially) to the original answer.  How about providing a working code example using the snippet tool?

Comment: Why use jQuery if it isnt even needed.... now a days you can simple use css. I worked it out with the accepted asnwer. Maybe this is also for you something to learn about :)

Comment: Thanks! i'd prefer jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the `height` of the element to `100%`. If the parent is not 100% of the screen, then you'll need to set the parent height as well. If your HTML structure looks like this...

```
<html>
<body>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

...then you'll need to set the `height` of all of those to `100%`:

```
html, body, div.row, div.col {
    height:100%;
}
```

To create the scrollbar, you can set overflow to scroll:

```
.col {
    overflow:scroll;
}
```